# Rails JSON Parameter not parsed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, reactjs, parsing

I have a registration form in ReactJS and want to to send the user data (name, email, password) in JSON format to my rails API. Rails then does not parse my JSON data into parameters.

Routes

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
    get '/list_users' => 'users#index'
    post '/register_user' => 'users#register'
end
```

User Controller

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
    def index
        @users = User.all
        render json: @users
    end

    def register
        puts params.inspect
        @user = User.new(name: 'TEST', :email => params[:email], :password => params[:password])
        #@user = User.new(name: 'User', email: 'controller@user.com', password: 'password') (this works)
        @user.save
    end
end
```

puts params.inspect outputs:

```
<ActionController::Parameters {"controller"=>"users", "action"=>"register"} permitted: false>
```

Registration form

```
postData(){
    var myHeaders = new Headers();
    myHeaders.append('Accept', 'application/json')
    myHeaders.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

    var data = JSON.stringify({
        name: "Test",
        email: "test@post.com",
        password: "password"
    })

    fetch("http://127.0.0.1:3000/register_user",{
        method: 'POST',
        headers: myHeaders,
        mode: 'no-cors',
        body: data
    })
    .then(function(res){ return res.json(); })
    .then(function(data){ alert( JSON.stringify( data ) ) })
    .catch( (ex) => {
        console.log("Fetch failed" + ex);
    });
}
```

parameter wrapping for JSON is enabled in the config.
Thanks for the help!

Comment: The `myHeaders.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');` part of your frontend code triggers your browser to send a CORS preflight OPTIONS request. Setting `mode: 'no-cors'` won’t prevent the browser from doing that. So if the `http://127.0.0.1:3000/register_user` server isn’t configured to handle OPTIONS requests and return the right CORS headers in response to them, then that preflight fails and the browser stops right there and never moves on to even trying to send the POST request from your code.

Comment: thanks, i did edit my rack::cors config in rails and changed mode to cors in the frontend, no everything works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

configuring Rack::Cors to accept OPTIONS did the trick, like sideshowbarker explainend in his comment.

application.rb

```
config.middleware.insert_before 0, Rack::Cors do
  allow do
    origins '*'
    resource '*', :headers => :any, :methods => [:get, :post, :options]
  end
end
```

and in the frontend

```
mode: 'cors'
```

Answer (score 0):

JSON parameters in this case will not have symbolic keys, but string ones. Try this instead:

```
@user = User.new(name: 'TEST', :email => params['email'], :password => params['password'])
```